# Handling Application level Errors in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, error-handling

I was wondering if someone can show me a good way to handle errors in my PHP app, that i am also easily able to reuse in my other scripts.

So far i have been using the following functions:

**Inline Errors**

```
function display_errors_for($fieldname) {
    global $errors;

    if (isset($errors[$fieldname]))
    {
        return '<label for="' .$fieldname. '" class="error">' . ucfirst($errors[$fieldname]). '</label>';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**All Errrors**

```
function display_all_errors($showCounter = true) {
    global $errors;

    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($errors as $errorFieldName => $errorText)
    {
        if ($showCounter == true)
        {
            $counter++;
            echo '<li>' . $counter . ' - <label for="' .$errorFieldName. '">' .$errorText. '</label></li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li><label for="' .$errorFieldName. '">' .$errorText. '</label></li>';
        }
    }
}
```

I have a $errors = array(); defined on the top of my global file, so it is appended to all files.

The way i use it is that, if i encounter an error i push a new error key/value to the $errors array holder, something like the following:

```
if (strlen($username) < 3) {
    $errors['username'] = "usernames cannot be less then 3 characters.";
}
```

This all works great and all, But i was wondering if some one has a better approach for this? with classes? i don't think i want to use Exceptions with try/catch seems like an **overkill** to me.

I'm planning to make a new app, and i'll be getting my hands wet with OOP alot, though i have already made apps using OOP but this time i'm planning to go even deeper and use OOP approach more extensively.

What i have in mind is something like this, though its just a basic class i will add further detail to it as i go deeper and deeper in my app to see what it needs.

```
class Errors
{
    public $errors = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Initialize Default Values

        // Initialize Methods
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        //nothing here too...
    }

    public function add($errorField, $errorDesc)
    {
        if (!is_string($errorField)) return false;
        if (!is_string($errorDesc)) return false;
        $this->errors[$errorField] = $errorDesc;
    }
    public function display($errorsArray)
    {
        // code to iterate through the array and display all errors.
    }
}
```

Please share your thoughts, if this is a good way to make a reusable class to store and display errors for an entire app, or is getting more familiar with exceptions and try/catch my only choice?

Comment: Exceptions aren't really complicated, you should get yourself comfortable with them - eventually, they will most likely simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine a reason for creating a distinct class for as trivial task as *echoing several text strings into browser*.
Or I am missing something.

I see no point for the function even.

Personally I have in my templates (where I need it) the code block like this

```
<? if ($data['errors']): ?>
<div class="errors">
  <ul>
<?   foreach ($data['errors'] as $e): ?>
    <li><?=$e?></li>
<?   endforeach ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<? endif ?>
```

and find it quite enough

Answer (score -1):

If you are into OOP, you should use framework like Zend Framework. In ZF there is an action helper for general error/result messages: **FlashMessenger**

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger

Comment: flashMessenger is not a way to handle error to me, but just an action helper that allow you to persist a message between to request using the $_SESSION.

Comment: actually what @Zubair1 asks is not really error handling, but something like validation `$errors['username'] = "usernames cannot be less then 3 characters.";`

Comment: according to the link you sent, its not what i'm looking for.
It just shows a method to transmit messages from one page to another using sessions.

`The FlashMessenger helper allows you to pass messages that the user may need to see on the next request.`